# Pass multiple props to component in react-materialui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to pass the styles and text to the reactjs component using PropTypes, but I'm getting the error that **TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined** and its point the error to **{typo.header}**

Unable to pass 2 different props into react component. I'm sure I'm not passing the props correctly, I'm learning reactjs and not sure how to do this correctly. Can some guide me how to do this.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

import './App.css';
import { AppStyle } from "./AppStyle";

import { Typos } from "./AppTypo";

function SurveyApp(props) {
  const { classes, typo } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <div className={classes._header}>
      </div>
      <div className={classes._body}>
        <div className={classes.__formContainer}>
        <Card className={classes.card}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography>
              {typo.header}
            </Typography>
            <Typography>

            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

SurveyApp.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  typo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
export default withStyles(AppStyle, Typos)(SurveyApp);
```

AppStyle.js:

```
export const AppStyle = {
  wrapper: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  _header: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#295e94',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  _body: {
    width: '100%;',
    height: 'auto',
    minHeight: 'calc(100% - 100px)',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'start',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  __formContainer: {
    width: 750,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -30
  },
  '@media (max-width: 480px)': {
    __formContainer: {
      width: '100%',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: -30
    }
  }
}
```

AppTypo.js:

```
export const Typos = {
  header: "User Experience",
  subHeader: "This is intended to improve your experience."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not providing the props correctly.

`export default withStyles(AppStyle, Typos)(SurveyApp);`

Does not do what you think it does with `Typos`.

Besides that, you have two different definitions for `header`: `header` and `_header`. The style you pass via `withStyles` is `_header`, from `AppStyle`. That's the one you should use.

You should not try to pass non-style information via `withStyles`, which is what it looks like you're trying to do with `Typos`. Those need to come in from the parent component, or since this is the parent, just use the imported `Typos.header`.

I recommend you [read more on props in general](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) to get a better idea of what they are for an how to use them.

In the future, you may find using [React's Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is better for handling styles.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: `import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();`

Comment: I'm actually following https://material-ui-next.com/demos/cards/ example

Comment: I'm not using `<SurveyApp typo={Typos}/>` I'm using `PropTypes`